# How to show all Case When Then records even if NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case, case-when

i have to display how many users voted for poll **2**, but separated in age ranges.

My current query works fine; but I'm having trouble when a specific range doesn't have any users in it. For example, if no users between the ages of 40-49 voted for poll **2**, then the result should be:

- **age_1 [13-19] = 0**
- age_2 [20-29] = 3
- age_3 [30-39] = 1
- **age_4 [40-49] = 0**
- **age_5 [50+] = 0**

...but instead I'm getting this:

- age_2 [20-29] = 3
- age_3 [30-39] = 1

So, what I need is for all age ranges to appear in the results, even when there are no matches. This is my current query:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN age BETWEEN 13 AND 19 THEN "age_1"
    WHEN age BETWEEN 20 and 29 THEN "age_2"
    WHEN age BETWEEN 30 and 39 THEN "age_3"
    WHEN age BETWEEN 40 and 49 THEN "age_4"
    WHEN age >= 50 THEN "age_5"
END as age_range,
COUNT(*) AS q
FROM (SELECT user.id_user AS id_user, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user.birthday, CURDATE()) AS age FROM user) AS udata
JOIN poll_vote ON poll_vote.id_user = udata.id_user
WHERE poll_vote.id_poll = 2 AND udata.age IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY age_range
ORDER BY age_range
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de06ca/1) with the example data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a left join with your totals and coalesce.

```
select totals.age_range, coalesce(ages.q,0) total from 
( 
    select 'age_1' age_range 
    union select 'age_2' age_range 
    union select 'age_3' age_range 
    union select 'age_4' age_range 
    union select 'age_5' age_range ) totals 
left join (
  SELECT
CASE
    WHEN age BETWEEN 13 AND 19 THEN "age_1"
    WHEN age BETWEEN 20 and 29 THEN "age_2"
    WHEN age BETWEEN 30 and 39 THEN "age_3"
    WHEN age BETWEEN 40 and 49 THEN "age_4"
    WHEN age >= 50 THEN "age_5"
END as age_range,
COUNT(*) AS q
FROM (SELECT user.id_user AS id_user, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user.birthday, CURDATE()) AS age FROM user) AS udata
JOIN poll_vote ON poll_vote.id_user = udata.id_user
WHERE poll_vote.id_poll = 2 AND udata.age IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY age_range
ORDER BY age_range
  ) ages
on totals.age_range = ages.age_range
```

-- results

age_range   total

age_1   0

age_2   3

age_3   1

age_4   0

age_5   0

Comment: Worked out great. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your SQL Fiddle. It made it easy to work with your question!